# How does square of Euclidean norm define quadratic cone

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry

An n-dimension quadratic cone is defined as $$Q^n=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:x_1\geq\sqrt{x_2^2+x_3^2+\cdots+x^2_n}\right\}.$$

I read that $||x||^2_2\leq y$ if and only if $(1/2, y, x)\in Q^{n+2}.$ This statement looks very confusing to me. $(1/2, y, x)\in Q^{n+2}$ seemingly means $$\frac12\geq \sqrt{y^2+||x||^2_2}.$$
How is this related to $||x||^2_2\leq y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not seem to be true. The exact statement is (see e.g. [here](https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/cqo.html#rotated-quadratic-cones)):

$ \left\| x \right\|^2_2 \leq y \Leftrightarrow (1/2, y, x) \in \mathcal{Q}_r^{n+2}$, where $\mathcal{Q}_r^n$ is the **rotated** quadratic cone, given by

$$
\mathcal{Q}_r^n = \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \ \middle|\
  2x_1 x_2 \geq x_3^2 + \dots + x_n^2
\right\}
$$

In this case, both directions are easy to verify.

Comment: @Vladimir: I'm not sure about expressing it directly, but my guess would be that you can't. On the other hand, the rotated quadratic cone is standard in the literature.